# Android animation should enter from left, wait for some time and then leave from right in repeat

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a layout which I want to enter from left and stay for few seconds and then I want it to leave from right. To achieve this, I have written following code:

Here I am setting the data in the layout:

```
private void loadDoctor(int doctorsInTheList) {
    if (myDoctors.size() > 0) {
        User doctor = myDoctors.get(doctorCarouselPosition).getDoctor();
        BindingUtil.setDoctorImageResource(binding.header.docProfile, doctor);
        binding.header.docName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        binding.header.tvAddDoctor.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        binding.header.docSubTitle.setText(R.string.text_your_doctor);
        binding.setDoctor(doctor);
        if (doctorsInTheList > 1) {
            setAnimation(binding.header.yourDoctorLayout);
        }
    }
}
```

And the setAnimation() function is :

```
public void setAnimation(View view) {
    if (getContext() != null) {
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.slide_to_right);
        view.setAnimation(animation);

        animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Animation animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.slide_right);
                        view.setAnimation(animation1);
                    }
                }, 1450);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is my slide_to_right animation:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <translate
            android:duration="500"
            android:fromXDelta="-8%p"
            android:toXDelta="0" />
   </set>
```

Here is my slide_right animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="1500"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="100%p" />
</set>
```

loadDoctor() I am calling every 3450 milliseconds to set new data.

Please help, I am stuck in this since yesterday.

Comment: what is your animation doing now? what is not working?

Comment: It's coming from left once and just staying there forever.

Answer (score 0):

I can see you use view.setAnimation. Where do you start the first animation?

See the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAnimation(android.view.animation.Animation)) for setAnimation. If you want to start the animation immediately when setting it use startAnimation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Achieved it already. There was problem with the time that I set. Now It's working fine. I am executing the second animation after interval of some time. Thanks for your efforts by the way.